# WPF: The attached property "MouseDown" can only be applied to types that are derived from "Object"

Tags: wpf, xaml

if I try to add a `MouseDown` event to my `<Window>` it says this: `The attached property "MouseDown" can only be applied to types that are derived from "Object".`

In my other projects, it works just fine.

This is my whole code:

```
<Window x:Class="Sentral_V.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sentral_V"
        xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Opacity="1"
        Topmost="True"
        Background="Black"
        Title="Sentral V" Height="450" Width="800" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5">
        <Grid Background="#FF1B1027" Margin="100,30,0,0">
            <Grid Margin="-100,0,700,0" Background="#FF3A1761">
                <Button x:Name="ChooseDLL" Width="80" Height="80" Content="Choose DLL" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF291058" Foreground="White" Click="ChooseDLL_Click">
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="2"/>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Resources>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Background="#FF110125" Margin="-100,-30,0,420">
                <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="20" Foreground="White" Background="#FF2A194A" Click="CloseButton_Click">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="2"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="MinimizeButton" Content="_" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="715,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="30" Height="20" Foreground="White" Background="#FF2A194A" Click="MinimizeButton_Click">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="2"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/61807025-d4c4-41e0-b648-b11183065009/mousedown-event-not-working-wpf?forum=wpf

Comment: Just ran into this myself with KeyDown. It has been working fine until today. I uninstalled VS2019 because I am only using VS2022 now. I wonder if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: @nnaem I just did a Clean Solution and a Rebuild Solution and it compiled successfully. The Error List still showed the same errors. I ran the program from the debugger and it ran fine. I closed and re-opened VS and the solution and the errors are now gone. Try just closing VS and re-opening and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: That weird error happens rarely and when it does, I can't use the designer at all, it says "invalid markup", I think I can't compile too